# Simple Salesforce Wrapper authentication Python

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm trying to use the "simple_salesforce_wrapper" but can't even pass the authentication. I'm sure the email, password and token are correct.

```
from simple_salesforce_wrapper import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='email@address.com', password='mypassword', security_token='osdifhgsdjflkjsdfoj', sandbox=True)
```

Response:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sandbox'
```

When I remove the "sandbox=True" I got this:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sandbox'
```

So what does it want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put in a quick patch to fix the issue and upgrade the library to 0.3.0

For sandbox connection, params will now look like:-

```
>>> from simple_salesforce_wrapper import *
>>> SALESFORCE_INSTANCE = {
...     "username": "...",
...     "password": "...",
...     "security_token": "...",
...     "domain": "Test", # Sandbox
... }
>>> sf = Salesforce(**SALESFORCE_INSTANCE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this package is that is based on an old version this package:

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce

You can see that there used to be such a parameter as sandbox here:
https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/v0.64.0/simple_salesforce/api.py#L37

You can try with an older version of the package (simple-salesforce), but it's below version 1.0.0 so I wouldn't expect too much

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried simple-salesforce. It's working for me, as they have domain="test" parameter for sandbox. But they don't have anything for conversion leads to accounts. What are my options then? 

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used SalesForce.

You can see in the code that simple-salesforce-wrapper used SOAP to convert leads.
https://github.com/afrobeard/simple-salesforce-wrapper/blob/master/simple_salesforce_wrapper/utils.py#L6

You could look in the salesforce documentation to see if this is still possible and try to add some functionality.